# Got a Deployment error in GlassFish

Tags: glassfish, oracle-adf

I tried to deploy ADF 12.1.3 application in GlassFish server 4.1.0, and got the following error during the deployment
note: Copied Adf essentials 3.1.2 to lib folder in GlassFish, ADF application is 12.1.3 version, GlassFish version is 4.1.0

---

Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [MegatronApplicationOCS_07012015] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: file:/C:/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/schemas/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 16; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/weblogic-application.xml in archive [MegatronApplicationOCS_07012015]. TargetNamespace.1: Expecting namespace 'http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-application', but the target namespace of the schema document is 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application'.. Please see server.log for more details.

---

Any help to fix this issue

Thanks

Comment: Do you know where this file comes from - `META-INF/weblogic-application.xml` ? Is it in your application? I would say that the file is not compatible with what GlassFish expects. I would remove the file and use GlassFish-specific descriptor instead - glassfish-application.xml

Comment: Thanks, I will check it

Answer (score 2):

Did you set your project deployment platform in JDeveloper to be Glassfish?
"Go to Application -> Application Properties-> Deployment
Go to Platform and choose Glassfish 3.1 from the drop down list. Click ok to go back to your project.
"
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/deploying_oracle_adf_applications_to

Also - for Glassfish 4 you'll want JDev 12.2.1.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/122-cert-2708091.html#ApplicationServers